# Вывод значений из элемента класса

Tags: права, классы, c++

```
class Mechanic{
      char *Name;
      int Experience;
      char *Category;
      char *Producing;
      int InPlan;
      int CurrentlyMade;
      public:
          //Тут описанны всякие конструкторы и деструктор
      void Print(class Mechanic &X);
};

//И собственно сама функция.
void Print(class Mechanic &x){
     cout << "Name: " << x.Name;
     cout << "Experience: " << x.Experience;
     cout << "Category: " << x.Category;
     cout << "Producing: " << x.Producing;
     cout << "InPlan: " << x.InPlan;     
     cout << "Currently made: " << x.CurrentlyMade;  
//Компилятор пишет, что эти данные приватные и всё тут.
}
```

Comment: И каков будет вопрос?

Попробуйте не писать функцию Print, а описать метод Mechanic::Print

Comment: Вах. Да, компилятор не жалуется больше. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

по умолчанию все переменные и методы внутри класса объявляются как private, что означает что всё что вне класса не может получить доступ к ним...

если объявить Print() как член класса, она сможет получить доступ к приватным полям и методам, второе решение это объявить Print() как friend по отношению к Mechanic...

---

почитайте про модификаторы доступа private,public,protected и то как всё изменяется при наследовании...

Comment: Да, спасибо. В комментарии к вопросу ответили уже. Решилось объявлением Print() членом класса.